# implementing merge sort for singly linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

im trying to implement merge sort on linked lists. I know how to do it on arrays, following similar logic I attempted for singly linked lists.
I have made functions for adding the data into respective list, sorting them separately using "sort" function in my code below (for which I have used bubble sort technique).

when I run, I get segmentation fault error. I have narrowed down the problem to mergesort function which might be obvious lol. I understand that my code isnt efficient but that is not the main concern at this moment. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
  { int data;
    struct node *next;
  };

typedef struct node n;

n* add(int a, n *head);
void display(n *head);
n* sort(int size, n *head);
void mergesort(n *h1,n *h2,int s1,int s2);

n* h3=NULL;

void main()
 { int size1,size2,i,x;
   n *head1=NULL, *head2=NULL;

   printf("Enter no. of elements in the first list: ");
   scanf("%d",&size1);
   printf("Enter elements of first list: ");
   for(i=0;i<size1;i++)
     { scanf("%d",&x);
       head1= add(x,head1);
     }
   printf("Enter no. of elements in the second list: ");
   scanf("%d",&size2);
   printf("Enter elements of second list: ");
   for(i=0;i<size2;i++)
     { scanf("%d",&x);
       head2= add(x,head2);
     }
    printf("List 1 before sorting: ");
    display(head1);
    printf("\nList 2 before sorting: ");
    display(head2);
    printf("List after mergesort: ");
    mergesort(head1,head2,size1,size2);
    display(h3);
 }

n* add(int a, n *head)
  { n *temp,*z=head;
    temp = (n*)malloc(sizeof(n));
    temp->data=a;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
      {
      head=temp;
      }
    else
    { while(z->next!=NULL)
        z=z->next;
      z->next=temp;
    }
    return head;
  } 

void display(n *head)
 { n *temp=head;
   if(head==NULL)
     printf("List is empty");
   while(temp!=NULL)
     { printf("%d-->",temp->data);
          temp=temp->next;
        }
  } 

n* sort(int size, n*head)
  { n *b, *f;
    b=head; f=head->next;
    int i,j,temp,flag=1;
    for(i=1;i<size;i++)
      { b=head; f=head->next;
        for(j=0;j<size-i;j++)
         { while(f!=NULL)
           { if(b->data >f->data)      
            { temp=b->data;
              b->data=f->data;
              f->data=temp;
              flag=0;
            }
           b=b->next;
           f=f->next; 
           }
          }
        if(flag==1)
         break;
     }
    return head;
  }


void mergesort(n *h1,n *h2, int s1, int s2)
  { int i,j,k;
    h1=sort(s1,h1);
    h2=sort(s2,h2);
    for (i=j=k=0;k<s1+s2;)
       { if(h1==NULL || h2==NULL) //no elements left in either list
           break;
         if(h1->data <= h2->data)
          { h3=add(h1->data, h3);
            k+=1; i+=1;
            h1=h1->next;
          }  
         else 
          { h3=add(h2->data, h3);
            k+=1; j+=1; 
            h2=h2->next;
          }
          
       }
    for(;i<s1;) //adds leftover elements 
    { h3=add(h1->data, h3);
      h1=h1->next;
    }
    for(;j<s2;)
    { h3=add(h2->data, h3);
      h2=h2->next;
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you add the remaining elements after one of the lists is exhausted, you advance the node pointer, but you don't increment `i` or `j`, which you use to control the loop.

Comment: In general, your merge function applies an array implementation to a linked list problem, which means that you must keep the indices, lengths and pointers in sync. I recommend to treat the list as a list and to implement merging only via node pointers, which is much simpler and straightforward.

Comment: `void mergesort(n *h1,n *h2, int s1, int s2)` You could return a pointer to the resulting list instead of void.

Comment: @MOehm adding the increment to the loops did the job, I missed it somehow. thanks for your help. regarding using array implementation for linked lists, I'm unsure of the other ways and I thought of making use of what I know. Definitely a stupid way :)

Comment: @wildplasser yes I had a return type added before but while my trial and error adventure I forgot to change it back. thanks